# SAS Macro to extract many variables from one variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm not able to find a starting point since I'm really new to SAS.

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
customer id number volume
1        ab  10     5
1        cd  7      3
2        xy  15     2
2        ab  3      50
```

I want to create a new dataset, in which I need a new variable for every distint id. 
In the row in which the id appears, number and volume shall be multiplied in the new variable. The new dataset should look like this:

```
customer id number volume ab cd xy
1        ab  10     5     50 .  .
1        cd  7      3     .  21 .
2        xy  15     2     .  .  30
2        ab  3      50    150 . .
```

Does anyone have an idea? Maybe the solution is really easy, but every comment is appreciated, because I'm really really new to SAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use a macro.  Arrays should handle this for you.

```
data want;
set have;
array flagvars ab cd xy;  *an array of your 3 new variables;
do _i = 1 to dim(flagvars);  *iterate one to the dimension of the array (# of vars in it);
  if upcase(vname(flagvars[_i])) = upcase(id) then flagvars[_i] = number*volume;  *if the name of the variable is identical to the id value, set that member of the array to the desired value;
end;
run;
```

If you have a lot of them, you can construct a macro variable with the list of array variables:

```
proc sql;
select distinct id into :idlist separated by ' ' from have;
quit;
```

then use

```
array flagvars &idlist.;
```

in place of the written out list.

Alternately, you could PROC TRANSPOSE if you pre-create the number*volume variable.

```
data have;
input customer id $ number volume;
total = number*volume;
datalines;
1        ab  10     5
1        cd  7      3
2        xy  15     2
2        ab  3      50
;;;;;
run;
proc sort data=have;
by customer id;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=have_t;
by customer id;
copy number volume;
var total;
id id;
run;
```

The `ID` statement names the variables based on the argument (in this case, `id`).  `Copy` appends variables not used in the transpose.  You have to be sorted by `customer id` to get this to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! But I have another probably stupid question ;-) There are actually 952 different ids so I can't write them in the code directly. I there any possibility to store them in the array beforehand?

Comment: I edited a second solution plus a way to get that list automatically.

Comment: seems like this answer was accepted, indicating as such helps everyone